Scrapy request on another URL while staying in the same function
I am inside a function, where I want the price of the size from its URL, I want to return to the same iteration and then append the size into the list named size_details. How do I do that?
Here's my code:
def start_requests():
    # some other code which initializes other variables
    sizes = get_sizes()

def get_sizes():
    sizes = get_sizes_data()
    for size in sizes:
        size_name = size['name']
        size_url = size["url"]
        # we need to get the size_price here by doing a scrapy request on size_url
        size_details.append({
            'name':size_name,
            'price':#need this value
        })
    return size_details

i have tried to create another function named get_size_price() and call it using this piece of code: Request(url=size_url, callback=self.get_size_price)
But i am unable to get my desired result.

Don't do it in the same function. Use another method, pass the name variable as an argument, scrape price in the new method, and then yield the result.
